# Docker with syslog driver, duplicated but truncated / garbled lines

Tags: docker, rsyslog

I'm trying to get my docker containers to write to syslog as my first step to managing logging of a handful of containers on a single box.

Configuration is shown below:

`cat /etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
    "tag": "docker"
  }
}
```

`cat /etc/rsyslog.d/10-dockerd.conf`

```
# Log docker generated log messages to file
:programname, isequal, "docker" /var/log/docker
& stop
```

However this results in duplicated/half truncated lines in the log (just running the `hello-world` image, but also happens on my own images:

`cat /var/log/docker`

```
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]:
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: Hello from Docker!
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: correctly.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]:    (amd64)
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]:    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]:    to your terminal.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: inal.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: t ubuntu bash
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: https://hub.docker.com/
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: ker.com/
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: For more examples and ideas, visit:
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: rted/
```

e.g.

```
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: correctly.
...
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]:    to your terminal.
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: inal.
...
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
Jun  4 13:47:03 hostname_here_ docker[12146]: t ubuntu bash
```

It does not appear to be related to the length of the line. This is a RHEL7.6 image in AWS. Other configuration (docker/rsyslog) is default.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Which Docker did you install?

Comment: I knew I'd missed something. `Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77156`